# get, using ffmpeg, the RTSP response code

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, shell, python, rtsp

It's possible get using the ffmpeg the RTSP response code?

I need collect the information from RTSP header, similar to the HTTP header. But using 'curl' i dont think it would be possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Double posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76813894/get-using-ffmpeg-the-rtsp-response-code

Comment: What is the RTSP response code ?